# Analytical solution to predict array size of binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I'm constructing a binary tree for a sequence of data and the tree is stored in a 1-based array. So if index of parent node is idx,
the left child is 2 * idx and the right is 2 * idx + 1.

Every iteration, I sort current sequence based on certain criteria, select the median element as parent, tree[index] = sequence[median], then do same operation on left(the sub sequence before median) and right(the subsequence after median) recursively.

Eg, if 3 elements in total, the tree will be:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
```

the array size to store the tree is also 3

4 elements:

```
    1 
   / \
  2   3  
 /
4
```

the array size to store the tree is also 4

5 elements:

```
      1 
   /     \
  2       3  
 / \     /
4 null  5
```

the array size to store the tree has to be 6, since there is a hole between 4 and 5.

Thus, the array size is only determined by number of elements, I believe there is an anlytical solution for it, just can't prove it.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why is there a hole?  Normally when we pack a binary tree into an array like this, there are no holes and the size of the array required to store N elements is N.

Comment: The holes exist because I want to ensure every node with index i has its left child at 2 * i and right child at 2 * i + 1, and when partition the sequence, left subsequence is always >= right subsequence. Take 5 elements as example, after first partition, left branch has 2 and 4, right has 3 and 5, drill down further with left, 2 becomes root and 4 is its left child, right child is a hole in array index 2 * 2 + 1 = 5.

Comment: Or simply put, I wanna be able to traverse the tree by index instead of pointers, so I allow holes in array rather than packing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every level of a binary tree contains twice as many nodes as the previous level. If you have `n` nodes, then the number of levels required (the height of the tree) is `log2(n) + 1`, rounded up to a whole number. So if you have 5 nodes, your binary tree will have a height of 3.

The number of nodes in a full binary tree of height `h` is `(2^h) - 1`. So you know that the maximum size array you need for 5 items is 7. Assuming all the levels are filled except possibly the last one.

The last row of your tree will contain `(2^h)-1 - n` nodes. The last level of a full tree contains `2^(h-1)` nodes. Assuming you want it balanced so half of the nodes are on the left and half are on the right, and the right side is left-filled, that is, you want this:

```
             1
        2         3
     4    5    6     7
    8 9      10 11
```

The number of array spaces required required for the last level of your tree, then, is either 1, or it's half the number required by a full tree, plus half the nodes required by your tree.

So:

```
n = 5
height = roundUp(log2(n) + 1)
fullTreeNodes = (2^height) - 1
fullTreeLeafNodes = 2^(height-1)
nodesOnLeafLevel = fullTreeNodes - n
```

Now comes the fun part. If there is more than 1 node required on the leaf level, and you want to balance the sides, you need half of `fullTreeLeafNodes`, plus half of `nodesOnLeafLevel`. In the tree above, for example, the leaf level has a potential for 8 nodes. But you only have 4 leaf nodes. You want two of them on the left side, and two on the right. So you need to allocate space for 4 nodes on the left side (2 for the left side items, and 2 empty spaces), plus two more for the two right side items.

```
if (nodesOnLeafLevel == 1)
    arraySize = n
else
    arraySize = (fullTreeNodes - fullTreeLeafNodes/2) + (nodesOnLeafLevel / 2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer still has some flaw, but should be easily fixed. The fact is the leaf level is more complicated. Take your 11 elements tree as example, #9 will be the left child of #6, # 10 left child of #5, and #11 left child of #7.

Comment: @HaoliangJiang Then you need to specify your requirements better in the initial post. My answer solves the problem that you asked.

Comment: @HaoliangJiang If my answer helped you out, it's customary to upvote it or mark it as accepted.

Comment: It helped me. I upvoted your answer. And I still think it need some refinement. As you already noticed, the tree I'm trying to build is balanced. I have not explicitly indicated it is balanced but from the description, every time remaining elements are divided into two implies it is balanced. While the example you illustrated is not balanced. A balanced tree need to be balanced recursively, so if both 8, 9 are under 4, the two subtrees under 2 are not balanced, the subtree with root node 4 has two more elements than the subtree with root node 5.

Comment: @HaoliangJiang It should be a simple matter of dividing the leaf nodes in half right and left, and then recursively dividing those in half, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't have any holes.  They are created by your partitioning algorithm, but that algorithm is incorrect.

For 1-5 items, your trees should look like:

```
  1       2       2       3       4
         / \     / \     / \     / \
        1       1   3   2   4   2   5
                       /       / \
                      1       1   3
```

The easiest way to populate the tree is to do an in-order traversal of the node locations, filling items from the sequence in order.

Comment: Sorry my bad for providing an even confusing example, those number are just # of element not their actual value. In real world, I'm building a variant of kd-tree, so every time drilling down one level in the tree, the partition criteria is re-decided by which x,y,z dimension is the largest. I just got the whole sequence at once, and partition them recursively and dispatch element to right slot in the array. Anyway, I kind of figure it out. Thanks for all the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm close to formalizing a solution. By intuition, first find the maximal power of 2 < N, then check whether the N - 2^m is even or odd, decide which part of the leave level need be growed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int32_t rup2 = roundUpPower2(nPoints);
    if (rup2 == nPoints || rup2 == nPoints + 1)
    {
        return nPoints;
    }
    int32_t leaveLevelCapacity = rup2 / 2;
    int32_t allAbove = leaveLevelCapacity - 1;
    int32_t pointsOnLeave = nPoints - allAbove;

    int32_t iteration = roundDownLog2(pointsOnLeave);
    int32_t leaveSize = 1;
    int32_t gap = leaveLevelCapacity;
    for (int32_t i = 1; i <= iteration; ++i)
    {
        leaveSize += gap / 2;
        gap /= 2;
    }
    return (allAbove + leaveSize);
```